# Can I submit application on the deadline?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, deadlines

If grad schools says the deadline is Jan. 15th, do I have to submit application before Jan. 15th? Or I can still submit on Jan. 15th?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most commonly the deadline is inclusive, i.e., "January 15" means that the deadline is "at some moment during January 15". What does this mean can vary:

- For **online** applications, it's usually 23:59:59.
- For **mailed** applications, there are two options and exactly one of them is true:

  - either the *poststamp* has to be January 15;
  - or it has to *arrive to the institution* by January 15.
- For applications you **deliver in person**, usually the *opening hours* of the office where you have to bring it apply.

In either case, it should be specified in the conditions.

And please remember that **timezones** can play a role here, and everything is *in the timezone of the institution where you apply* unless stated otherwise.

---

/From comments/

**If you doubt the precise conditions, just call them or e-mail them and ask for clarification.**

It will cost you less than solving any troubles afterwards.

Comment: I've seen universities with a 5pm online deadline for another time consideration.

Comment: @ChrisC I write "usually" and "it should be specified in the conditions" and "if you doubt ... ask for clarification". I hope this is enough to make sure that what I write is not the definite answer :)