# Is there any paper submission deadline timezone convention?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, deadlines

Conference papers and special issues of Journals usually have deadlines for submission. However, it is sometimes not clearly stated what timezone the deadline is in. Is there any convention for this? Is it the location localtime, UTC or others?

Comment: *However, it is usually not clearly stated what timezone the deadline is in* - really? All the conferences I submit to specify the timezone, either on the conference site or the paper submission site. Can you give an example?

Comment: In general, you don't want to put yourself in the position of submitting in the last 24 hours, so it shouldn't matter... If in doubt either assume worst case or contact them and ask.

Comment: @keshlam ... and in practice, 80% or so of submissions get uploaded or updated on the last day :)

Comment: @ff524 My experience is exactly opposite. I've yet to see en example when the timezone is specified. I usually expect it ste timezone of the person signed below the call for papers.

Comment: related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/15727/1471

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Primarily, you should really try to find out what time zone a conference uses rather than assume a specific one. As ff524 says, even if it is not on the web site, the submission site will often tell you.

That being said, at least in my discipline, there are two conventions that are common:

- **Local time** at the conference location
- **AOE (anywhere on earth)**, more formally known as [Howland Island time](http://www.worldtimezone.com/time/wtzresult.php?CiID=42242).

The latter is probably the more common one.

*(Howland Island time is called "Anywhere on Earth" because it is the last time zone. That is, if you say that a deadline is friday, 24:00 AOE, the real deadline will nowhere be earlier than friday, 24:00, reducing the possibility of feel-bad moments when paper writers forgot about time zones and assumed their own time zone.)*

Comment: I've also seen "local time wherever the paper submission site is hosted" (not necessarily the conference location) pretty often. And conferences that use EDAS for submission tend to use NYC time a lot.

Comment: @ff524: "local time wherever the paper submission site is hosted" -- by the active preference of the organiser, or due to lazy/buggy programming on the site?

Comment: I've seen local time at the client from where the documents are *submitted*.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a situation where the deadline did not specify any timezone, and I have emailed the organizers but they said *"there is no timezone for the deadline"*, which is more confusing.

My professor said just assume that it is Anywhere on Earth (AoE) timezone, 12 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).